# Efficiently get file deltas for backups

Tags: lvm, incremental-backup, thin-provisioning

With many large Xen sparse image files that have to be backed up, I'm looking for a way to do this efficiently both in terms of disk space (saving space with a differential tool like duplicity, bup, rsync, womble's lvmsync, etc.) and disk/network bandwidth. Unfortunately, the space and bandwidth requirement nixes the tools I just mentioned as they will scan files' entire contents to find deltas between source and destination.

So, I want to avoid the following pitfalls:

- Blind copying of entire files
- Intensive scanning of entire files to generate checksums for comparison
- Redundant copies of data on the same volume (due to COW or other feature) -- and this must hold for both the source and destination volumes.
- Significant performance degradation during normal system use

A search did lead me to one cool example that meets all of the above criteria... OS X Time Machine when using *sparsebundles* as the source volume. Oh well, that's not going to work on Linux. But it was interesting to see how simply the mtimes of the individual 'band' files in a sparsebundle tell you which bits have been modified since the last backup date -- instantly, with almost zero effort. The space savings is not perfect since the bands are 4MB long, but still very good.

Eventually, while working with thin-provisioned logical volumes I came across the thin provisioning test suite which includes an [example of using thinp allocation data](https://github.com/jthornber/thinp-test-suite/blob/master/incremental_backup_example) for quick differential backups. I thought I had found my solution... just put the images on a thin LV and use snapshots!

But then I realized this would use too much space on the source volume as well as slow it down. Normal LVs are for short-term use.

I still got to wondering if there is some script-fu or crafty config options that could make a snapshot logical volume act like a 'phantom' snapshot: It would record only the block allocation data associated with modified blocks, but not copy-on-write the data blocks themselves. This phantom snapshot could be read by a backup script and instantly pick out the modified blocks for a given LV. (I guess some would call this a journal.) When the backup finished successfully, it could delete the existing phantom snapshot and create a new one to hold modification info for the next differential backup.

The solution doesn't have to involve LVM, but thinking of a solution this way allows me to present the desired solution in a more solid form. There has to be some way to reach this level of backup efficiency on Linux.

Comment: That sounds like changed block tracking - I'm not up to speed on this in the Xen world but google throws up some references.

Comment: CBT appears to be a feature specific to VMware ESX. I need a solution that can work with regular Linux distributions.